# AJAX request error despite data is being updated successfully. "Unexpected Token <"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The question is very specific to my code written, and not able to find any solution.
I have an AJAX request that is sending some data to the server and updating the contents on the database. On firing the AJAX, the data is being updated in the database correctly, but AJAX displays error on the screen.

This is my AJAX request:

```
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {'postData':JSON.stringify(postData)},
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(data) {
            successmessage = 'Data was succesfully updated';

            $("#contentID").html(successmessage);


        },
        error: function(data) {
            successmessage = 'Error';
            $("#contentID").html(successmessage);

        },


});
```

My PHP request is this:

```
if(isset($_POST['postData'])){
$jsonData = json_decode($_POST['postData'],true);
$length = count($jsonData['ID']);
$ID = $jsonData['ID'];
$fieldText = $jsonData['fieldText'];
for($j=0;$j<$length;$j++) {
$langText = $fieldText[$j];
$id = (int) $ID[$j];

$update = "UPDATE mytable  SET myText = '$langText'
                WHERE ID = $id";
$mysqli->query($update) or die(mysql_error());
}}
```

On debugging, I found the error message "Unexpected Token <".

The json that is being sent to "update.php" is valid json as I have tested this before. I'm posting the code that is capturing the values and creating a json before stringify it.

```
var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var c = 0;
var fieldName = [];
var fieldText = []
var ID = [];
for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
    var node = node_list[i];
    if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
        fieldName[c] = node.name;
        fieldText[c] = node.value;
        ID[c] = node.id;
        c++;
    }
}
var postData = {
    fieldName: fieldName,
    fieldText: fieldText,
    ID: ID
};
var dataString = JSON.stringify(postData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(postData));
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: You are requesting json from server but not returning anything or if there is a mysql error returning text. `$.ajax` will trigger error for json parsing, not just for connection issues

Comment: Change error to `error: function( jqXHR , textStatus, errorThrown ) {//code to display textStatus and errorThrown here (they are strings)}`  Then you will see what the server really thinks about what happened.

Comment: Question. What is the structure of `postData` before you stringify it?

Comment: @DFriend: the structure is:  {var postData = {
        fieldName: fieldName,
        fieldText: fieldText,
        ID: ID
    };
 var dataString = JSON.stringify(postData);
 console.log(JSON.stringify(postData));}

Comment: @charlietfl: how this can be fixed. any suggestions please

Comment: @DFriend: I implemented your code and is saying "unexpected token <"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the

```
dataType:"json"
```

to

```
dataType: "html"
```

thanks